# docker daemon restarting containers when not required to

Tags: docker

According to this [documentation](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/host_integration/), I should be able to add `-r=false` - to the docker daemon - however adding this to the `DOCKER_OPTS` seems to have no effect.

Rebooting causes it to restart containers that I want to run under supervision.

On ubuntu, this is in `/etc/init.d/docker`:

```
DOCKER=/usr/bin/docker
DOCKER_PIDFILE=/var/run/docker.pid
DOCKER_OPTS="-r=false"
```

Comment: See if `DOCKER_OPTS="-r=false"` helps? Double `=` in same line without quotes seem weird.

Comment: nope - just tried that - same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Ubuntu - you will want to use the service command, not init.d script.

```
service docker restart
```

to restart.

The config for this is in:

```
/etc/init/docker.conf
```

You can add -r=false in there, after the -d parameter - and it works. Ignore the /etc/init.d/docker script on ubuntu.